# Como filtrar relacionamentos no adonis?

Tags: node.js, adonisjs

Eu passo essa query:

```
const filter = request.input('filter')
const queryBookQuestions =  BookUnitQuestion
                                    .query()
                                    .with('book_unit')
                                    .with('user')
                                    .with('book', (builder) => {
                                        builder.where('id', request.params.id)
                                    })
```

Nessa query eu retorno todos os livros de uma unidade de um livro com o objeto `book_unit` relacionado a ele, o user e trago apenas as perguntas do livro que receber como parâmetro `(book.params.id)`

Agora eu preciso filtrar as perguntas por unidades.
Eu tenho esse filtro que funciona corretamente procurando pela descrição da pergunta:

```
if(filter){
            if(filter.search("description") !== -1){
                let description = filter.match(/(?<=description~contains~').*?(?=')/)
                queryBookQuestions.where('description', 'ilike', '%'+description[0]+'%')
            }
```

Esse filtro funciona bem porque acredito que é aplicado direto no modelo `BookUnitQuestion`. Mas agora, preciso filtrar a Unidade, que é um relacionamento, ou seja, preciso retornar as perguntas que tiverem apenas na unidade que eu filtrar. Eu tentei algo como:

```
if(filter.search("unit") !== -1){
                let unit = request.input('filter').match(/(?<=unit~contains~').*?(?=')/)

                queryBookQuestions.where('book_unit.unit', unit[0])}

        }
```

Porém dessa forma eu recebo:

> select count(*) as "total" from "book_unit_question" where
>   "book_unit"."unit" = $1 - missing FROM-clause entry for table
>   "book_unit"

Answer (score 0):

Parece uma questão do momento de processamento dos argumentos. Tente trocar o where para whereRaw. Deve resolver.